# Putting multiple condition with more raster to Con tool in ArcGIS Raster Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, con

I have three rasters and need to make a condition including all of them. The condition should look like `Ras1>(Ras2*85 + (Ras3/4)), Ras1 if true, 0 if false`.

Can anybody here help me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
Con("Name_of_Raster_1" > ("Name_of_Raster_2"*85+"Name_of_Raster_3" / 4),"Name_of_Raster_1",0)
```